# base 58 is missing the 1 char

Tags: python, python-2.7

I was trying to build a nosql database to store the bitcoin blockchain in order to make a explorer. just a personal project in order to learn something, I knwow that there is ready to work explorers on github that you can just clone and deploy.

So there are millions of addresses, I wanted to store them in sub-tables to speed up the searches, something like this : addr_<3_first_char_of_an_addr>

To do that I used this script to find the first int value that generates a 3 char base 58 number.

```
# coding: utf-8
# yes, that header is valid :)

import base58
import codecs

def int2bytes(i):
    hex_value = '{0:x}'.format(i)
    # make length of hex_value a multiple of two
    hex_value = '0' * (len(hex_value) % 2) + hex_value
    return codecs.decode(hex_value, 'hex_codec')

for i in range (10000000):
    b58 = base58.b58encode(int2bytes(i))
    print b58
    if (len(b58)) == 3:
        break
print "so 3 char = " + str(i)
```

output :

```
zp
zq
zr
zs
zt
zu
zv
zw
zx
zy
zz
211
so 3 char = 3364
```

And the first base58 3 char number is 211 (for int(3364)), shouldn't it be 100?

Thanks.

Comment: You should read up on [Base58](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base58). Fundamental to its design is that it doesn't include zero, so `100` isn't a valid Base58 value.

Comment: well 111 should be the first then

Comment: Granted, the Wikipedia article I linked to doesn't get into the specifics of the math, but if you play around with the module a bit, or perhaps do some more reading of other sources, you will see that the character `1` in that particular Base58 encoding corresponds to the (common base-10 arithmetic notion of) integer zero. For the same reason that we don't write 000 when we do plain, old, regular arithmetic, the string `111` wouldn't come up in that particular Base58 encoding. (But notice the different sequence of characters in the Base58 alphabet used by Ripple.)